# sum() of column by distinct() id column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(leads.source_cost) AS cost,
       COALESCE(SUM(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) AS revenue,
       (COALESCE(SUM(assignments.recipient_revenue), 0) - SUM(leads.source_cost)) AS profit,
       date_format(leads.updated_at, "%m/%d/%Y") AS date
FROM "leads"
    LEFT JOIN "assignments"
        ON "assignments"."lead_id" = "leads"."id"
           AND "assignments"."deleted_at" IS NULL
WHERE leads.updated_at
BETWEEN "2017-08-24 04:00:00" AND "2017-08-26 03:59:59"
GROUP BY "date";
```

I need the `sum(leads.source_cost)` to use distinct `leads.id` in my query because a lead can be assigned more than once.

How do I do this? I can't do a group by because I need the group by to use the `date` alias.

Comment: Presumably this is now resolved by interpolation of the answer to your other question

Comment: I do not understand, how "the `sum(leads.source_cost)` can use `distinct leads.id`"?